# How do you access variables from different classes in Java?

Tags: java

I have been having trouble accessing a variable from another class.  Here are my variables:

```
public static byte agressivePoints = 0;
public static byte peacefullPoints = 0;
public static byte meanPoints = 0;
public static byte happyPoints = 0;
public static byte sadPoints = 0;
```

I put them outside of my Main class.  In this class, I am tying to access those variables from the other class to put them in this one.

```
public class Check_Anwser {
    public static void Check_Answer(int Input) {
        boolean TryAgain = false;

        do {
            switch (Input) {
                case 'a': {
                    ++agressivePoints;
                    break;
                }
                case 'b': {
                    ++sadPoints;
                    break;
                }
                case 'c': {
                    ++meanPoints;
                    break;
                }
                case 'd': {
                    ++peacefullPoints;
                    break;
                }
                case 'e': {
                    ++happyPoints;
                }
                default: {
                    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid anwser. Please try      again");
                }
            }
        } while (TryAgain != true);
    }
}
}
```

But when I do this, there is an error. For some reason, the variables from the first class aren't shared with the second class.

Comment: `++OtherClassName.aggressivePoints;`

Comment: Your code will be much easier to read if you indent it properly - you might spot things like the missing `break`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That actually worked!

Comment: Ok Andy, I will take your suggestion and indent my code. Thanks!

Comment: Your question has been answered, but for future reference it's helpful to include the error you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expression `Main.aggressivePoints` to access these global variables.

I encourage you to keep learning about object-oriented design, so that you can understand why it will be better when you create objects and protect data like this inside them. It's called encapsulation.

Comment: I thought Java has no global variables?

Comment: @user3437460 Define "global variable."

Comment: It was from your answer.

Comment: @user3437460 I know what I meant by "global variable." I'm asking what you mean by it, so that I can answer your question according to your interpretation of global variable.

Comment: The term "global variables" to my understanding is the global variables we see in language like C++. But as far as I know, Java only has local variables, class variables and instance variables. Using the term "global variables" in Java can be misleading.

Comment: @user3437460 So your definition requires something other than Java as a language? No, Java does not have global variables then. But I think that goes without saying.

Comment: For certain, my definition for "global variable" requires something outside Java simply because Java do not have global variables. If a high reputation user would admit a mistake (be it a small typo error), I would truly respect him for that.

Comment: @user3437460 The respect of an anonymous user who splits hairs with tautologies isn't as valuable to me as trying helping a new programmer avoid the evils of global variables.

Answer (score 3):

> How do you access variables from different classes in Java?

If the variable (or member) of another class is non-static. You can create an instance(object) of that class and access to its variable, for example:

```
class Warrior
{
    private int strength;
    public int getStrength(){
        return this.strength;
    }
}

class TestRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Warrior w = new Warrior();
        w.getStrength();    //Access to strength of warrior via a Warrior object
    }     
}
```

If the member is public, you will be able to access it directly like:

```
w.strength;
```

But when you learn the concept of encapsulation and data protection, you will realize generally we will try to make the instance variables as private.

---

As for static members, they belongs to the class and not individual objects. So it is encouraged you access them via the class name, for example:

```
class Warrior{
    public static final int SPEED;    //let say speed for all warriors are unified
}

class TestRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int speed = Warrior.SPEED;    //Access a class variable via the class name
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access variables from other class say A
to call the variable into your main class use (instance of classA).varaibleName
In your case corresponding class name of the variable say class A contains

```
public static byte agressivePoints = 0;
```

by creating an instance of the class like

```
A inst =new A();
++inst.agressivePoints;
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is have a Variables class, in which holds all your variables, and inside the Correct_Answer class you could simply call

```
Static Variables v;
```

and infront of each of the variables you wish to call just do c.VARIABLENAME;

Comment: These aren't constants.

Comment: That is just a class name thought of really quick, he could easily change it to something else. I didn't state that they were constants.

Comment: By convention, only constants have all uppercase variable names in Java.