# Access to non-static variable from static context

Tags: java

I am trying to access a boolean variable `stay` from my class `MontyHall` but cannot because it is non-static and i am trying to access it in a static context
Here is the code:

```
public void updateStatistics(Door door1, Door door2, Door door3)
{
    this.numGames = this.numGames + 1;
    oneDoor(door1, 0);
    oneDoor(door2, 1);
    oneDoor(door3, 2);

    if (MontyHall.stay == true){
        this.numStay = this.numStay + 1;
    }
    else{
        this.numSwitch = this.numSwitch + 1;
    }
}
```

The variable stay is located in class `MontyHall`. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very confused how to fix this
Properties of class `MontyHall`:

```
public class MontyHall {
  boolean stay;
  Door A = new Door("A");
  Door B = new Door("B");
  Door C = new Door("C");

  public MontyHall(Door a, Door b, Door c){
    this.A = a;
    this.B = b;
    this.C = c;
  }}
```

Comment: Looks so much better now after indentations.

Comment: Can you show your code for `MontyHall`?

Comment: aha @user3437460 very true didnt realize it wasn't properly indented

Comment: @user3437460 What part? Just the constructor?

Comment: A couple notes to make your program a little simpler  `this.numGames = this.numGames + 1;` is usually more simply written as `this.numGames++` also `if (MontyHall.stay == true){` can be rewritten as just `if (MontyHall.stay) {` This is pretty much just personal preference but it makes the code a little simpler and cuts down on keystrokes

Comment: @MatteoColombi The part where you declared `stay` in `MontyHall` and any other parts which deal with that variable.

Comment: Did not understand..in the example the static var is accessed in a non static context, so its correct

Comment: @user3437460 been updated

Comment: @JackWilliams I will update, thank you for the tips :), any idea about the problem at hand?

Comment: @MatteoColombi Take a look at my solution. Let me know whether it works now.

Comment: There is no global variable here, or anywhere in Java.

Comment: @EJP I fully agree with you, but unfortunately some people don't think it that way. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161586/how-do-you-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-java/35161703?noredirect=1#comment58045072_35161703

Answer (score 1):

Your code `MontyHall.stay` is the part where you are trying to reference it statically (by using the class name).

A non-static field will need an instantiated object in order to reference. In this case, if this method is within MontyHall, then you can use use `this.stay` in order to access it, instead of `MontyHall.stay`. If the method you've listed above is not within the MontyHall class then you will need to create a new MontyHall object like such: `MontyHall montyHall = new MontyHall();`

Alternatively, you may want to make your `stay` variable static, in which case just add a simple `static` keyword to the variable declaration.

Comment: but I am not calling MontyHall.stay in MontyHall, should have specified this my apologies

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I have updated my suggestion accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> am trying to access a boolean variable stay from my class MontyHall but cannot because it is non-static and i am trying to access it in a static context

Everything is clear now. Your variable `stay` is an instance variable which belongs to each individual object of class `MontyHall`. So you shouldn't contemplate making it `static` just to resolve the error.

To access an instance variable, you need to create an object first. (Since it belongs to a particular object and not a class):

```
MontyHall hall = new MontyHall();
hall.stay;    //access stay from object of MontyHall
```

In the rule of data protection and encapsulation, you may consider making `stay` variable ***private*** and use `getters` and `setters` to access it.

So if you set `stay` as private, you will access it like this:

```
hall.getStay();
```

---

Last but not least, Java do not have global variables. It is a rather common misconception to perceive class variables (static variables) as global.

Comment: I tried creating a get method but I am still getting a conflict with static vs. not Static

Comment: ` public boolean getStay(){
   return this.stay;
}`

Comment: @MatteoColombi Can you show me the line of code which gives you the error? Is it this `public boolean getStay(){ return this.stay; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just access variables from non-static contexts. You will have to instantiate the class first and then access bariable from that instance. So it would go something like this:

```
MontyHall a = MontyHall();
a.someVariable....
```

Note: variable should be accessible from other classes (would recommend encapsulation depending on situation).

More info in this thread: [calling non-static method in static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

You want to access a variable directly from the class, without creating an instance. To do so, the variable should be declared `static`. In that class, you should thus define it as follows:

```
public class MontyHall {
    public static boolean stay = true;
    .....
}
```

Now you can access it in the way you did.

**Edit**

Or, as the others have mentioned as well. If `stay` is a variable that can change within your class, you should make an instance first.

```
MontyHall a = new MontyHall(....);
a.stay; // This is the stay variable from MontyHall a
MontyHall b = new MontyHall(....);
b.stay; // This stay variable could have a different value
```

Comment: Not final. (Though the whole OP is a problem.)

Comment: Why should it be declared `final`?

Comment: You're correct, I changed it